# How to upload the file to another SFTP server from shell channel by using Jsch?

Tags: shell, unix, sftp, jsch

Step 1: Session connect

```
....
session.connect()
```

Step 2: Shell channel

```
channel = session.openChannel("shell");
```

Step 3: Execute ssh commands to login Unix server and go to the required path `cd /logs/server`

```
PrintStream shellStream = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());  // printStream for convenience 
channel.connect(); 
shellStream.println(command); 
shellStream.flush();
```

step 4: Get the file from Unix server and put into SFTP:

```
code to connect sftp channel and put the file from unix server to sftp.
```

So I want to upload the file (`logs/server/server.log`) from Unix server (which I logged in using shell channel) to SFTP server.

Both source and destination are remote.

Is it possible to do by using JSch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SFTP protocol (let alone JSch SFTP library) has no support for transfers between two remote servers.

If you have a shell access to one of the servers, you can try to transfer the files by using a command-line (OpenSSH) `sftp` client on the server. It's doable. Problematic is an authentication part, as it's non-interactive session. You would have to use an unencrypted private key, an agent forwarding or `sshpass`.

---

Obvious and simple implementation is to download the files from the "Unix" server to a local machine and then upload them to the "SFTP" server. But you need to use the SFTP channel, not the shell channel, for the download.